# Did Casting Crowns ever say why they chose their name?

Tags: culture

To put it another way, did Casting Crowns ever say what the inspiration for their name was? A friend thought "casting" meant making, as in pouring metal into a mold and casting crowns that way. I've always thought it was "casting" in the sense of throwing it, as in casting crowns away. The only support I have for my idea is

> [**Revelation 4:10-11**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rev+4%3A10-11&version=NIV)
>   10 the twenty-four elders fall down before him who sits on the throne and worship him who lives for ever and ever. They **lay their crowns before the throne** and say:
>
> 11 “You are worthy, our Lord and God, \
>       to receive glory and honor and power, \
>   for you created all things, \
>       and by your will they were created \
>       and have their being.”

I took a look at [Wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_Crowns), but they don't say anything about how or why the name was chosen. So, how and/or why *did* they choose that particular name?

Comment: -1 This appears to be a question about popular music. Frankly, I'd flag it but it's by a mod so that would be fruitless.

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User: Please bring it up on Meta if you want to. Also, you can go ahead and flag it; we mods never handle flags on our own content as a rule.

Comment: OK I've flagged it as off-topic i.e. not a question on Christianity. Would be a fine question some kind of popular music SE. However, I don't think that exists.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a popular (though Christian-related) music group.

Answer (score 3):

A little Googling turned up a list of 15 questions that fans asked the band. Within, there is this exchange:

> **4. MyGodIsEnough asks: What does the name "Casting Crowns" mean, and why did you decide to use it as the band name?**
>
> **Mark:** The Scripture is Revelation 4 where it talks about the 24 elders around the throne, putting their crowns before Him. For me, as a believer, if you’re not careful, little things will rise up in your life and become important. And it will create distance between you and God; and these little kingdoms don’t have to be bad things, sometimes they can be good things. They just take our focus away, and we have to let these kingdoms fall and fall before Him and make sure that we are setting apart Christ as Lord in our lives.

Indeed, the inspiration *was* Revelation 4:10-11, as suspected.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right verse, just the wrong version cf. [KJV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?dc=1&utm_expid=13466113-14.mkvZJx04TeSSGHAKrWaXKA.1&search=Revelation%204%3A10-11&version=KJV&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.biblegateway.com%2Fpassage%2F%3Fdc%3D1%26search%3DRevelation%25204%3A10%26version%3DKJV):

> 10 The four and twenty elders fall down before him that sat on the throne, and worship him that liveth for ever and ever, and **cast** their crowns before the throne, saying,
>
> 11 Thou art worthy, O Lord, to receive glory and honour and power: for thou hast created all things, and for thy pleasure they are and were created. (emphasis added)

Comment: It's at times like these that I wish there was a way to do a BibleGateway search across all versions. +1 for finding the right one.